# Dar formato a fecha Integer al mapear en Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo el inconveniente de tener valores de fechas en unas tablas de base de datos en formato Integer (ej: la fecha actual estaría almacenada como 20221107) pero la necesito como Date.
¿Hay alguna forma, al mapear la entidad, de hacer esa conversión para poder mapear el valor como Date y no cómo el original Integer?

Gracias comunidad!!!

Comment: Guardar la fecha como un `Integer` es un mal diseño como bien mencionas. ¿Ya esta considerado el asunto de las zonas horarias? Por ejemplo, si guardas un registro nuevo con la hora en 00:00:00 del dia de hoy, ¿se escribe en la base de datos como `20221107` o como `20221106` (Suponiendo que estás al oeste del meridiano de Greenwich)? Eso lo puedes averiguar tambien viendo el Locale que tiene seteado la base de datos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Jetto Martinez!!! En qué influiría lo que planteás a la hora de la conversión? Lamentablemente, el dato está prestablecido en la base de datos...

Comment: En que no sabemos si las fechas leidas deben tomar en cuenta la zona horaria o si se decidió guardar así para "evitar" pensar en eso. Piensa que si guardas un número, la BD jamás va a intentar hacer conversiones sin importar donde estés, por lo que es una "solución creativa" el no tratar la fecha como fecha y evitar pensar en zonas horarias. Para hacer la conversión de `Integer` a algún tipo de fecha, hay que saber si debemos tomar en cuenta eso o si podemos usar el valor tal y como viene.

Comment: A todo esto, estas usando JPA? JPA tiene mecanismos que ayudan mucho esto